# Is Insulated Ground Wire Required?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, wire

I am installing a new 240v receptacle in the garage to charge my electric vehicle.  The charger requires a 20 amp breaker and will pull 16 amps.  I plan to run 30' of 12/2 UF-B wire beneath the floor in the 3' crawl space to the outside wall electrical panel.  Question - must the ground wire be insulated or can it be bare?

Comment: Which type of 240V receptacle is this? NEMA 6?

Comment: Some chargers require 4 wire. The neutral is insulated and the equipment ground can be bare. What is the model of the charger?

Comment: EVSE = Chargers4evs model (see Amazon.com) while receptacle is NEMA 6-20

Comment: Also don't pay $26 for a 6-20R receptacle.  Sometimes Amazon's prices are cray.

Comment: I caught that Amazon bazaar price for the receptacle also.  Home Depot sells the same one for $5.28.  Leviton 20 Amp Double Pole Single Outlet, White Model # R52-05821-0WS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use standard 12-2 with ground on this outlet. The equipment ground wire is not individually covered.